# How do I assign a property source to a certain environment in micronaut?

Tags: java, micronaut

I am adding property values through my Application class like so

```
public class Application {

    @Loggable
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SecretManager secretManager = new SecretManager();

        Micronaut.build(null)
                .mainClass(Application.class)
                .propertySources(PropertySource.of(
                        "name",
                        mapOf(
                                "datasources.default.username", secretManager.getValue(
                                        "DATASOURCES_DEFAULT_USERNAME")
                                ))).start();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to change the value for datasources.default.username according to the environment by doing something like this. The following code does not work but is there a way to do something like this?

```
public class Application {

    @Loggable
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SecretManager secretManager = new SecretManager();

        if(environment == "Dev") {
            Micronaut.build(null)
                    .mainClass(Application.class)
                    .propertySources(PropertySource.of(
                            "name",
                            mapOf(
                                    "datasources.default.username", secretManager.getValue(
                                            "DATASOURCES_DEFAULT_USERNAME")
                            ))).start();
        } else {
            Micronaut.build(null)
                    .mainClass(Application.class)
                    .propertySources(PropertySource.of(
                            "name",
                            mapOf(
                                    "datasources.default.username", secretManager.getValue(
                                            "DATASOURCES_CUSTOM_USERNAME")
                            ))).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: Does the code you showed not work? If not, what is the error? If it does work, what are you trying to improve?

Comment: It does not work. I just provided the code to show that i want to be able to make it work by writing something similar to it. sorry if I was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `application-dev.yml` that assigns the property from the env var

`datasources.default.username: ${SOME_ENV}` for example